# include pjoject text file into publish dot net core

Tags: .net-core

In dot net core project. I have to include a text file from project folder to publish.
I used these codes but not working:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="PrintDtl\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="textfile.txt">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: ohh yes bro now its working ...before i tried this but used ** in position of file name.